# After using aws to send multiple messages to sqs, the sqs handler lambda lost part of the message request

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I send a message to sqs from other places, and the message will only notify the sqs handler lambda to output a log. There are no other time-consuming operations. The code is similar to:

```
  const sqs: AWS.SQS = new AWS.SQS()
   const params = {
       MessageGroupId: "testGroup",
       MessageDeduplicationId: uuid(),
       MessageBody: "My Message",
       QueueUrl: process.env.SQS_URL
   };

   await sqs.sendMessage(params).promise();
```

If it is a single message, everything is normal.
If I use await promise.all([p1,p2,p3]) for multiple messages, only part of the request can be received in the lambda that processes the message, and the other part is lost.

multiple messages:

```
await Promise.all([
   sqs.sendMessage(params1).promise(),
   sqs.sendMessage(params2).promise(),
   sqs.sendMessage(params3).promise()
])
```

sqs handler:

```
exports.handler = wapper(async (event: any, context: any) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false    
    logger.info('enter sqs handler----')
})
```

[image]

I also checked in the aws sqs dashboard monitoring chart that everything is normal, 100 messages were sent and 100 messages were received.
But in fact, it can be seen from the cloudwatch log that only part of the message triggers the sqs handler lambda when the message is consumed.

How can I solve the lost request problem?

sqs dashboard config:
[image]

Comment: "*only part of the request can be received in the lambda that processes the message, and the other part is lost*" - what do you mean by "part of the request"? In your example you're sending 3 requests, are you saying 1 or more doesn't get received by the lambda? What batch size does your lambda process? And do you know there's a function in the sqs sdk called `sendMessageBatch` which can send up to 10 messages at once, and is more efficient than calling `sendMessage` multiple times?

Comment: for example, if send 3 messages, i can see 3 received in the monitoring, and there are only 1-2 requests in the sqs handler.

Comment: I haven’t paid attention to the batch size. It should be the default value. I need to check it. In the actual case, we may have 100 messages to be processed, so this problem may still occur when using sendMessageBatch. I hope that the problem of sendMessage can be solved first, thanks

Comment: By default I think the batch size is 10, so a single lambda may process all 3 messages at once in a single event. Have you checked the event to see how many Records it contains? I have to guess as you haven't shown the code that actually processes the event, but if you're not looping through the array and processing each Record then that could be a reason for records to seem to disappear. Another cause could be if it takes a long time to process each record, and you have a DLQ setup with a low max visibility count, a message might get moved to the DLQ because it wasn't processed in time.

Comment: What you said about event.Records really reminded me. I checked the code and it was really a problem with event.Records. We have only used event.Records[0] before. Thank you very much.